# IndexOutOfBoundsException while trying to access elements of ArrayList of an ArrayList

Tags: java

I am trying to code for a Hackerrank problem https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/dynamic-array/problem I get this java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException whenever I try to implement this code but the result (x^lastAswer)%N is less than N and is well within the range:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int N = sc. nextInt(); //no. of sequences
    int Q = sc.nextInt(); //no. of queries

    int lastAnswer = 0;

    List<List<Integer>> seq = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(N);

    while(Q>0){
        int Qtype = sc.nextInt();
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        int y = sc.nextInt();
        if(Qtype == 1){
            seq.get((x^lastAnswer)%N).add(y);
        }
        else{
            seq.get((x^lastAnswer)%N).add(y);
            lastAnswer=y;
            System.out.println(lastAnswer);
        }
        Q--;
    }
    sc.close();   
}
```

Comment: `new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(N)` creates list which is able to store `N` elements without need to resize it (it sets its *initial* capacity), but it doesn't put any elements in list itself (its size is still 0). So since list is empty using `get(index)` throws exception because there is no element at specified index.

Comment: How do I initialize the list to store N such ArrayLists so that I can use the get(index) feature? In simpler words, how do I initialize an ArrayList which can store N ArrayLists, with each ArrayList initialized to be able to store N integers.

Comment: Simplest way would be using loop which will iterate N times and in each iteration you will `seq.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());`.